# How to click on link element after i element with specific text using watir?

Tags: html, ruby, watir

For this type of link I am happily using

```
@browser.link(:text => "Reports").when_present.click

<a href="/Reports/">Reports</a>
```

However I am struggling with this example

```
<a href="#">
  <i class="no-icon"></i>
  Staff
  <img src="/Images/Menu/arrow.gif" class="arrow">
</a>
```

I am wanting to click the link by text also but it is not found due to i element. I do not want to use xpath so can anyone advise a better way please.

Thanks

Comment: It's working for me. You don't have to write when_present anyway because now it's automatic. I tried with the following code and it's working `browser.link(text: "Staff").click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given below code works for me fine.

```
browser.link(text: "Staff").click
```

If it's not working, perhaps you may try by this

```
browser.element(link: "Staff").click
```

If it's still not working then write the following code

```
browser.element(xpath: "//img[@src='/Images/Menu/arrow.gif']/..").click
```

Remember `when_present` method is not necessary because that's automatic. WATIR automatically waits for button/link to exist, present, enabled.